# Unable to dequeue a plugin script. I think I've tried everything

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

---

EDIT - SOLUTION GIVEN IN COMMENTS

The problem was that I was initially hooking in at wp_enqueue_scripts so I wanted a high priority to make sure my dequeue was happening after the plugin's enqueue. When I switched to using wp_print_scripts (or more accuratly wp_print_footer_scripts) I should have switched to a low priority, as Jacob Peattie pointed out. That was all I needed to fix this. -JW

---

I'm trying to dequeue a script which is added by a plugin. Here is the code from the plugin...

```
class WC_Social_Login_Frontend {
    ...
    public function load_styles_scripts() {
        ...
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-social-login-frontend', wc_social_login()->get_plugin_url() . '/assets/js/frontend/wc-social-login.min.js', $script_deps, WC_Social_Login::VERSION, $load_in_footer );
    }
}
```

Nothing I have tried, thusfar, has stopped this script from loading. Here is my code which is inside of a mu-plugin I used instead of functions.php. I've tried hooking in at various places, none have worked.

```
    function jw_dequeue_social_login(){
        wp_dequeue_script('wc-social-login-frontend');
        wp_deregister_script('wc-social-login-frontend');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'jw_dequeue_social_login', PHP_INT_MAX );
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'jw_dequeue_social_login', PHP_INT_MAX );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jw_dequeue_social_login', PHP_INT_MAX );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'jw_dequeue_social_login', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Hopefully I'm an idiot and have missed something obvious. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you find where `load_styles_scripts` is hooked in the plugin? Somewhere should be something like `add_action( '???', array( $this, 'load_styles_scripts' ) );`, but `$this` might be something else, or missing. The important thing is finding the `add_action()` that runs `load_styles_scripts`.

Comment: Also, `PHP_INT_MAX` will be too _late_ for `wp_print_footer_scripts`, `wp_print_scripts` and `wp_footer` hooks. If the original function is run before those hooks, then the script will likely already be printed by the time your function for de-queueing them runs. Try changing those to `0`.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie ! That was the problem and now I feel like an idiot. But I'd rather feel like an idiot and have the problem solved...so thanks.

I was initially hooking in at wp_enqueue_scripts so I kept pushing the priority higher and higher then when I switched to using wp_print_scripts I still had 'must use high priority' in my brain. Changing it to 0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Jacob Peattie for answering this in the comments!

The problem was using a high priority with wp_print_footer_scripts when I should have been using a low priority.

```
function jw_dequeue_social_login(){
        wp_dequeue_script('wc-social-login-frontend');
        wp_deregister_script('wc-social-login-frontend');
    }

    add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'jw_dequeue_social_login', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `script_loader_tag` filter to catch and remove the actual HTML tag before it is output, eg.:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'remove_social_login_frontend', 10, 3 );
function remove_social_login_frontend( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'wc-social-login-frontend' === $handle ) {$tag = '';}
    return $tag;
}
```

Note you could also do this via a string match on the URL via the `$src` variable.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thankfully I didn't need to use it, but I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: very handy to know this one, for example if you are in the unfortunate place of having to apply a fix a 3rd party script, you can more easily point to a different source URL with the fix and have it working (until the developer hopefully incorporates the fix you reported in the next version.right? lol)